# what's the difference between pd.DataFrame and sklearn transformed SparseMatrix? why sklearn transformed SparseMatrix so fast?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, gensim, doc2vec

I'm currently working with a emotion analysis dataset which contains 100000 docs.

By using sklearn's `TfIdfVector`, i transformed these docs to a (100000, 20000) vecs. It works fine with `trains_test_split` and `LogisticRegression`, though it does take several minutes to print the result.

Then i tried `gensim.doc2Vec.Doc2Vec` model to train these docs to a (10000, 20000) vecs.
When the `doc2vec` generated, i transformed these vecs to a dataframe like these:

```
train_doc2vec = model.dv.vectors[:8000]
test_doc2vec = model.dv.vectors[8000:]

train_df = pd.DataFrame(train_doc2vec)
train_df.head(5)
```

all these works fine. But when it comes to `train_test_split`, it takes **more than hours**, but still not splitted..... i've tried to `del train_doc2vec and model` for saving memories, neither works out too...

```
del train_doc2vec
del model
```

Is there anyway i can do to making gensim generated doc2vec works faster, or anything wrong with me??

Answer (score 1):

Do you really mean a `(10000, 20000)` result from `Doc2Vec`? (What happened to the other 90,000 docs?)

I'm going to assume you mean `(100000, 20000)` instead: that you used `Doc2Vec` to create one vector per document.

`Doc2Vec` is a algorithm for creating *dense* representations: compressing the docs down to a far smaller number of dimensions, where none are `0.0`. Typical dimensionalities output by published `Doc2Vec` work are in the 100-1000 dimension count, *not* 20000.

So that's an initial error. (If you've been working off any docs/tutorial/guide that suggested such a large dimensionality, the author didn't know what they were doing, & you should discard that source. If you're not working off any docs/tutorial/guide demonstrating proper `Doc2Vec` usage, you should be! Just improvising from the whole range of possible parameters, and choosing something so far from the default and usual ranges as `vector_size=20000`, will lead to a lot of wasted time.)

Separately, despite that issue, I don't see whay `train_test_split()` would necessarily run long on a giant dense array, but I could imagine other steps (like `LogisticRegression`) taking longer. So perhaps that's the real delay in your other unshown code steps. Still, the real fix is to use `Doc2Vec` within its usual range of performance.

Comment: tks for the advice.  as i'm trying to distinct sentences from negative and normal. i tried using tfidf(20000 features)+lgb, f1_score is 79%. When it comes to word2vec(using google's pretrained and use average vec of words ) + lightgbm,  f1_score is so low, say only 65%.  So i think the problem i've faced is features are seldom. Then i tried doc2vec with 20000 features, and it seems the program blockked.

Comment: I can't recall seeing any project using 20,000 dimensions in `Doc2Vec`. Even published work on sets of tens-of-millions of documents – far more than your 100,000 –  I only recall seeing up to 1,000 dimensions used.